# Ошибка KeyError in beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, requests, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv


headers = {'accept': '*/*',
          'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/77.0.3865.90 Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'}


BASE_URL = 'https://www.klinikapawlikowski.pl/cennik/'
def parser(base_url, headers):
    data = []
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')

        divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'col-12 dropdown-list'})
        for div in divs:
            title = div.find('div', attrs={'class': 'dropdown-list__header__title'}).text


        title_procedure = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'dropdown-list__body__block'})
        for procedure in title_procedure:
            title_procedures = procedure.find('div', attrs={'class': 'dropdown-list__body__block__title'}).text
            data.append({'title_procedurere': title_procedures})
        opisanie_procedur = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'dropdown-list__body__block__item'})
        for procedur in opisanie_procedur:
            opis_procedures = procedur.find('div', attrs={'class': 'dropdown-list__body__block__item__title'}).text
            data.append({'opis_procedur': opis_procedures})

        cena = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'dropdown-list__body__block__item'})
        for cen in cena:
            ceny = cen.find('div', attrs={'class': 'dropdown-list__body__block__item__price'}).text
            data.append({'Cena': ceny})
    else:
        print('ERROR')

    return data

def files_writer(data):
    with open('parsed_cennik.csv', 'a') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        a_pen.writerow(('Title_proedure', 'Opisanie_procedur', 'Ceny'))
        for job in data:
            a_pen.writerow((job['title_procedurere'], job['opis_procedur'], job['Cena']))

data = parser(BASE_URL, headers)
files_writer(data)
```

Ошибка такая:

> a_pen.writerow((job['title_procedurere'], job['opis_procedur'], job['Cena']))
> KeyError: 'opis_procedur'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка `KeyError: 'opis_procedur'` означает, что у словаря отсутствует такой ключ.

Если в строчке `a_pen.writerow((job['title_procedurere'], job['opis_procedur'], job['Cena']))` выведите `print(job)`, то сможете в этом убедиться.

А причина в том, что у вас при заполнении `data.append` в одном элементе (`job`) за один раз может быть только одно из этих значений:

- `data.append({'title_procedurere': title_procedures})`
- `data.append({'opis_procedur': opis_procedures})`
- `data.append({'Cena': ceny})`

Если так и должно быть, а проблема в том, что словарь ругается, то вместо обращения по ключу через скобки, сделайте через метод `get`:

```
a_pen.writerow((job.get('title_procedurere'), job.get('opis_procedur'), job.get('Cena')))
```

Если ключа не будет, то `get` вернет `None`. Можно, кст, указать какое значение в отсутствии ключа возвращать, например `job.get('title_procedurere', '<unknown>')`

---

**UPD.**

Если у вас данные в `data` идут тройками и за один раз вы хотите по тройке обработать, то предлагаю попробовать такой алгоритм:

```
for i in range(0, len(data), 3):
    title_procedurere = data[i].get('title_procedurere')
    opis_procedur = data[i + 1].get('opis_procedur')
    cena = data[i + 2].get('Cena')
    a_pen.writerow((title_procedurere, opis_procedur, cena))
```

---

**UPD2.**

Неудержался и [немного попарсил](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dd6e20664b87a00988f81dd6dcb965604d24d21e/html_parsing/https__www.klinikapawlikowski.pl_cennik/main.py), и вот, что получилось:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv

headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                  '(KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/77.0.3865.90 Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'
}

BASE_URL = 'https://www.klinikapawlikowski.pl/cennik/'

def parser(base_url, headers) -> dict:
    data = dict()

    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code != 200:
        print('ERROR')
        return data

    soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')

    for header in soup.select('.dropdown-list__header'):
        # "Konsultacje", "Dermatologia kliniczna" и т.п.
        header_title = header.select_one('.dropdown-list__header__title').getText(strip=True)

        data[header_title] = dict()

        for block in soup.select('.dropdown-list__body'):
            # "Dermatolog", "Badanie histopatologiczne", и т.п.
            procedure = block.select_one('.dropdown-list__body__block > .dropdown-list__body__block__title').getText(strip=True)
            items = []

            for item in block.select('.dropdown-list__body__block__item'):
                title = item.select_one('.dropdown-list__body__block__item__title').getText(strip=True)
                price = item.select_one('.dropdown-list__body__block__item__price').getText(strip=True)
                items.append((title, price))

            data[header_title][procedure] = items

    return data

def files_writer(data: dict):
    with open('parsed_cennik.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        a_pen.writerow(('Title_proedure', 'Opisanie_procedur', 'Ceny'))

        # "Konsultacje", "Dermatologia kliniczna" и т.п.
        for header, procedures in data.items():
            # "Dermatolog", "Badanie histopatologiczne", и т.п.
            for procedure, items in procedures.items():
                for title, price in items:
                    a_pen.writerow((procedure, title, price))

data = parser(BASE_URL, headers)
files_writer(data)
```

Кусочек csv:

```
Title_proedure,Opisanie_procedur,Ceny
Dermatolog,Lek. Bartosz Pawlikowski,170 zł
Dermatolog,Lek. Klaudia Orłowska – Orlik,150 zł
Dermatolog,Lek. Magdalena Kutwin,150 zł
Dermatolog,Lek. Hanna Kowalska,150 zł
Dermatolog,Lek. Martyna Gabryjelska-Janiszewska,150 zł
Dermatolog,Lek .Wojciech Drzazga,150 zł
```

**PS.**

Хоть, в исходной странице ценников было 3 уровня вложенности данных, но сохранение делается для последних двух как было в вопросе, но это легко исправляется [добавлением еще одной колонки](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4e85dde70bf5489d7e7b70276dfb6ec4be36f348/html_parsing/https__www.klinikapawlikowski.pl_cennik/main.py#L62) и в `a_pen.writerow((header, procedure, title, price))`. Бонусом [по ссылке](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dd6e20664b87a00988f81dd6dcb965604d24d21e/html_parsing/https__www.klinikapawlikowski.pl_cennik/) можно будет посмотреть результат парсинга. Дополнительно включил туда и `json`